# Averages for ranges of values

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, range, average

I'm using Oracle SQL and i need help with a query.

I have the following table:

```
Age (int)
Salary (int)
```

Input for example:

```
Age | Slary
 18 | 5000
 18 | 10000
 20 | 11000
 24 | 9000
 21 | 6000
 21 | 7000
 22 | 6000
 28 | 22000
```

I need to calculate the average salary by ranges of ages. Each two years are a rage. Output for example:

```
Age Range | Average Salary
18 - 20   | 8666.666
19 - 21   | 8000
20 - 22   | 7500
21 - 23   | 6333.33
22 - 24   | 7500
23 - 25   | 7500
24 - 26   | 7500
26 - 28   | 22000
27 - 29   | 22000
28 - 30   | 22000
```

BTW, it's possible to split "Age Range" column into two different column: "Min Age" and "Max Age" if it's more easy to be implemented.

Any recommendation how to do that?

Comment: Provide some input please..

Comment: Is it intended that the 3-year ranges overlap?

Comment: @TheConstructor: I'm not sure i completely understood your question. The values in age column are unknown. It's possible that there will be no ages in the value of 34-36 for example, and therefor this range will not be included in the "Age Range" output column.

Comment: What happens when the youngest age is an odd number e.g. 19. Would you want the ranges to then be 19-21, 21-23, etc OR 18-20, 20-22, etc?

Comment: "18-20, 20-22" and that's since 18-20 it's a range which 19 included in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this might be what you want (it's in part adapted from the approach in the answer by Deepak Pawar, but adjusted to Oracle syntax). I noticed that the values for the `23-25`group is 9000 in my query but 7500 in your sample data, but I believe the sample data is incorrect and that 9000 is indeed the correct value (also for `24-26`).

Oracle isn't my database of choice and I'm sure the query can be improved by someone more familiar with Oracle development.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a03569/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE t ("Age" int, "Salary" int);

INSERT ALL 
    INTO t ("Age", "Salary") VALUES (18, 5000)
    INTO t ("Age", "Salary") VALUES (18, 10000)
    INTO t ("Age", "Salary") VALUES (20, 11000)
    INTO t ("Age", "Salary") VALUES (24, 9000)
    INTO t ("Age", "Salary") VALUES (21, 6000)
    INTO t ("Age", "Salary") VALUES (21, 7000)
    INTO t ("Age", "Salary") VALUES (22, 6000)
    INTO t ("Age", "Salary") VALUES (28, 22000)
SELECT * FROM dual;
```

**Query 1**:

```
WITH counter
AS ( 
  SELECT 
    LEVEL-1 low, 
    LEVEL+1 high
  FROM DUAL
  WHERE (LEVEL-1) >= (SELECT MIN("Age") FROM t)  
  CONNECT BY LEVEL-1 <= (SELECT MAX("Age") FROM t) 
)

SELECT 
  (low || ' - ' || high) "Age Range",
  Avg("Salary") "Average Salary"
FROM t 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN counter c ON t."Age" >= c.low AND t."Age" <= c.high
GROUP  BY low, high
ORDER BY 1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a03569/1/0)**:

```
| AGE RANGE |    AVERAGE SALARY |
|-----------|-------------------|
|   18 - 20 | 8666.666666666666 |
|   19 - 21 |              8000 |
|   20 - 22 |              7500 |
|   21 - 23 | 6333.333333333333 |
|   22 - 24 |              7500 |
|   23 - 25 |              9000 |
|   24 - 26 |              9000 |
|   25 - 27 |            (null) |
|   26 - 28 |             22000 |
|   27 - 29 |             22000 |
|   28 - 30 |             22000 |
```

Answer (score 1):

This may help (MSSQL script):

```
SELECT Cast(LowerLimit AS VARCHAR) + ' - '
       + Cast(UpperLimit AS VARCHAR) AgeRange,
       Avg(salary)                   averagesalary
FROM   MyTable t1
       RIGHT OUTER JOIN (SELECT Age     AS LowerLimit,
                                Age + 2 AS UpperLimit
                         FROM   MyTable) AS t2
                     ON t1.Age >= t2.LowerLimit
                        AND t1.Age <= t2.UpperLimit
GROUP  BY LowerLimit,UpperLimit
```